# php writing csv not getting line break

Tags: php, csv

i want to create a csv output with a new line to start with each set of data.
i get the file but there is no line break
[my output page](http://myoscapp.com/app_specials.php)

```
$values = mysqli_query($dbc, "SELECT specials.specials_id, specials.products_id,specials_new_products_price, products.products_image,  products.products_price,products.products_image, products.products_quantity,products.products_model,products_description.products_name,products_description.products_description
FROM specials
JOIN products_description
JOIN products
WHERE specials.products_id = products.products_id AND specials.products_id = products_description.products_id AND products.products_quantity>0");
while ($rowr = mysqli_fetch_row($values)) {
 for ($j=0;$j<$numberOfRows;$j++) {
  $csv_output .= $rowr[$j].", ";
 }
 $csv_output .= "\n";
}

}

print $csv_output;
exit;
?>
```

Comment: instead of using `"\n"` use the php constant `PHP_EOL`

Comment: Yes, there are line breaks there. They just won't show up in the browser. View the page source of your output page and you'll see them.

Comment: I'm not sure I got it right, do you mean "csv" excel file format? of this is just your variable name??

Comment: look at your HTML source, they're there alright.

Answer (score 0):

The "\n" is a linebreak, indeed.
But they don't show up in the browser.

Try `<br>` instead

Comment: `<br>` may not be a good idea if this is actually supposed to produce something like a CSV file.

Comment: No, you are right. But it is the best solution to create a linebrake in the browser @Don'tPanic

Comment: @Don'tPanic The OP isn't writing to a file, least not what they posted anyway. They're just `print`'ing. Had they been (writing to a file), then yeah.. `<br>` would not work.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I assumed they were just printing to test what they had so far. But who knows.

Comment: @Don'tPanic Exactly; *who knows* ;-)